# simple regexp in Matlab

Tags: regex, string, matlab

Let's say I have the following strings

```
begin: - number 1: word_12

begin: - number 3: word_31

begin: - number 3: word_11

begin: - number 9: word_43
```

Basically I just want to select the text after `number \d:` (ie, `word_12`, `word_31`, etc.) using a regexp in Matlab along these lines `regexp((?<=[number ]\d: .*),'match')` but I have no idea how to construct the regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = {'begin: - number 1: word_12';
     'begin: - number 3: word_31';
     'begin: - number 3: word_11';
     'begin: - number 9: word_43'};%a cell array of strings

re = '.*number \d: (.*)';

A = regexp(s,re,'tokens'); %a cell array of cells containing strings
```

The output of regexp is a little funny to work with, since you have to "dereference" the cell twice to get a string back out -- eg.

```
A{1}{1}

ans = 

    'word_12'
```

For lots more info, I've found Matlab's [regexp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) help page to be pretty useful.